# context with Jquery file upload and Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, jquery-file-upload

I'm having a context problem with jquery-file-upload and Backbone. In the fileupload 'done' callback, I want to call another function defined in the Backbone view, but I lose the context.

```
class MyBackboneView extends Backbone.view

    initialize_fileupload: ->
        $('form#my_form').fileupload
            done: (e, data) ->
                this.some_function()

    some_function: ->
        ...
```

The error returned in the browser console is
"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'some_function'" because "this" no longer refers to the Backbone view, but the jquery form element.

Is there a way to access that function in the view from the callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every function (`->`) has its own context (`this`). That includes `done: (e, data) -> ...`, as well as `initialize_fileupload: -> ...`. And, in this case, they each have their own context value, so `this.some_function()` isn't referencing your `view`.

So, you'll have to define `done` to keep the surrounding context (the `view`). This can be done in CoffeeScript by defining it with the "[fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow)" (`=>`) instead:

```
initialize_fileupload: ->
    $('form#my_form').fileupload
        done: (e, data) =>
            this.some_function()
```

It can also be accomplished by storing the context value in a scoped variable:

```
initialize_fileupload: ->
    thisView = this
    $('form#my_form').fileupload
        done: (e, data) ->
            thisView.some_function()
```

Or by [binding the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to the surrounding context:

```
initialize_fileupload: ->
    $('form#my_form').fileupload
        done: ((e, data) ->
            this.some_function()
        ).bind(this)
```